# Validation Error When Trying To View Rails Web App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Maybe someone can help me with this...

I've generated a basic rails app in Cloud9, and started the server with...

rails server -b $IP -p $PORT

...but when I then use the assigned IP to view the app I get a validation error. Would anyone know what might be causing it?

[Cloud9 Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxXxD.png)

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz8WM.png)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to run the app on [image]
http://127.0.0.1:8080. I think this would work. Maybe it's not recognizing your assigned $IP

Comment: Hey... thanks for the suggestion, but I've been trying that too and it's failing to open any page at all. I just get a message saying 'can't connect to server 127.0.0.1'. It could be something simple that I'm missing as it's the first time I'm setting this up.

Comment: Is it possible to share the link to the code with me? I can try to help you fix it. It's hard to determine what the error is without checking.

Comment: I don't really have any code to share just yet :) I'm working through Michael Hartl's rails tutorial here : https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app and I've generated everything as mentioned, created the db, etc., and it's when I get to Section 2.2 where I start the rails server that I'm running into the problem. I've tried a few different IP addresses and ports but none of them work.